# Help me please, to check this code? why it run catch?? Android

Tags: android

```
public void getDataPermission() {

    final TextView twCheck = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    final TextView twPackageInfo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    final ListView lwPackage = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    PackageManager pm = lwPackage.getContext().getPackageManager();
    PermissionInfo permissions;
    try {
        permissions = pm.getPermissionInfo("com.android.music",
                PackageManager.GET_PROVIDERS);
        Iterator it = ((Collection<PackageInfo>) permissions).iterator();
        // Temporary string
        String temp = "";
        // Counter package
        int i = 0;
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            PackageInfo rf = (PackageInfo) it.next();
            temp = rf.toString();
            twPackageInfo.append(temp);
        }

        temp = permissions.toString();
        twPackageInfo.append(temp);
        twCheck.append(" : Process try");

    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        twCheck.append(" : Process catch");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

In my emulator has package:com.android.music.
I don't understand that why app process catch?
App should be to process catch. Why?

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Is pm null at your try catch block? I assume your talking about an exception that is being thrown, correct? If so can you provide your logcat output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you can call `getPermissionInfo()` only for permissions
that you declared in your manifest using `<permission>` tags.

Maybe this will help, although I am not sure what are you trying to accomplish with your code...
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/security.html#declaring

If this doesn't make it any more clear, then sorry, I can't help you :(

Comment: Radivojevic Bombe
I try it. Don't work. App process "catch".
:(
You can run "try" with my code.

Help me please. T_T 

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: You think Can I get detail about permission(in tag <permission>) another app(installed app)?
I think it may be yes,but Now I don't ideal to do it.
Sorry for my bad English

Comment: You want to check if, for example, app named `com.app.something` has, for example, `ACCESS_INTERNET` permission? I think it CANNOT be done, at least not that way :(

Comment: I think you don't understand me.
I want to know that each Application has requested "permission" to do anything, On my code.